# BusyBox login applet returns "login: /etc/passwd: bad record"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, busybox

I am learning embedded Linux with help of [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1789530385) book. I built the kernel and the Busybox for the BeagleBone black and booted to shell successfully(with `rdinit=/bin/sh` command line parameter), then i decided to "Configuring user accounts" so as mentioned in this book i created following files :

- rootfsStagingDirectory/etc/passwd:

> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
> daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/false

- rootfsStagingDirectory/etc/shadow:

> root::10933:0:99999:7:::
> daemon:*:10933:0:99999:7:::

- rootfsStagingDirectory/etc/group:

> root:x:0:
> daemon:x:1:

- rootfsStagingDirectory/etc/inittab:

> ::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
> ::respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 console

And i booted to the kernel with `console=ttyO0,115200 rdinit=/sbin/init` command line parameters as is mentioned in the book. The kernel boots successfully and asks me to enter the *username*, but after i hit the enter button it returns:

`login: /etc/passwd: bad record`

And i can not login. I searched for acceptable format of passwd file for BusyBox login applet, but i could not find any things.

Comment: Check again the format. You forgot a `:` (for the missing GECOS). Check carefully with the manual page (volume 5) of passwd

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Please check again, each line has 7 filed so we need 6 `:` and we have 6 `:` for each line